# How do I save a dictionary of lists of dataframes in Python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, save

I currently have a dictionary that maps state codes to a list of two dataframes that contain data about the states. I am getting this data from a SQL request but I don't want to make that SQL request and do all the preprocessing steps everytime I analyze this data, so I want to save it all and I can just reupload it whenever I need it. How do I download this dictionary of lists of dataframes and how do I load it back later too?

P.S I am coding all this in Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: `pickle` should work.

Answer (score 0):

To download and load the dictionary of lists of dataframes in Python you can use the `pickle` module, which allows you to serialize and deserialize objects.

To save the dictionary:

```py
import pickle

with open('pandas_data.pickle', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(state_data, f)
```

This code will save the dictionary as a binary file named `"pandas_data.pickle"` in the current or specified directory.

To load the dictionary:

```py
import pickle

with open('pandas_data.pickle', 'rb') as f:
    data = pickle.load(f)
```

**However, I only advise you to use `pickle` module if you are sure that the loaded data is safe to load.**